# How to create a tkinter toggle button?

Tags: python, tkinter, toggle, python-2.x

I've been working on a text editor using Tkinter in Python 2.7.
A feature that I'm trying to implement is the Night Mode, where the user can toggle between a black background and a light one, that switches from light to dark with a click of the toggle button.

```
from Tkinter import *

from tkSimpleDialog import askstring

from tkFileDialog   import asksaveasfilename
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

from tkMessageBox import askokcancel

Window = Tk() 
Window.title("TekstEDIT")
index = 0

class Editor(ScrolledText):

    Button(frm, text='Night-Mode',  command=self.onNightMode).pack(side=LEFT)

    def onNightMode(self):
    if index:
        self.text.config(font=('courier', 12, 'normal'), background='black', fg='green')

    else:
        self.text.config(font=('courier', 12, 'normal'))

    index = not index
```

However, on running the code, it is always in the night mode and the toggle doesn't work. Help.
Source Code: http://ideone.com/IVJuxX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background and fg are set only in the if-clause. You need to set them also in the `else` clause:

```
def onNightMode(self):
    if index:
        self.text.config(font=('courier', 12, 'normal'), background='black', fg='green')

    else:
        self.text.config(font=('courier', 12, 'normal'))

    index = not index
```

---

i.e.,

```
else:
    self.text.config(font=('courier', 12, 'normal'), background='green', fg='black')
```

Comment: The `UnboundLocalError` is due to the assignment to `index` which makes it a local variable by default when you really want it to refer to the global variable. The quick fix is to add the statement `global index` inside the function. But a better fix would be to avoid using a mutable global and instead make `index` an instance attribute, `self.index`.

Answer (score 4):

You can import tkinter library (Use capital letter for python 2.7):

```
import Tkinter
```

Create tkinter objects...

```
root = tk.Tk()
```

...and tkinter button

```
toggle_btn = tk.Button(text="Toggle", width=12, relief="raised")
toggle_btn.pack(pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Now create a new command button called "toggle" in order to create the effect of "toggle" when you press playing on the relief property (sunken or raised) :

```
def toggle():

    if toggle_btn.config('relief')[-1] == 'sunken':
        toggle_btn.config(relief="raised")
    else:
        toggle_btn.config(relief="sunken")
```

At the end apply this behaviour on your button:

```
toggle_btn = tk.Button(text="Toggle", width=12, relief="raised", command=toggle)
```

Comment: Your code isn't formatted properly. Also, code-only answers aren't usually as good with code plus an explanation. Can you explain a bit why your code solves the problem?

Comment: I do not know English well but I know very well python:
What do you mean formatted propely? For Python 2.7 works fine !!!!
Copy it and paste into a text file and save it as .py!
Test before giving a bad comments!!!

Comment: At the time I wrote the comment, the body of `toggle` was indented the same as the `def` statement and you could _not_ copy and paste it. Look at the history of the edits and you'll see your original version was edited by someone else to fix the indentation.

Comment: was the first time and I was wrong with the editor of stack overflow for the code but I assure you that I was in good faith and that the code has always worked.
Next time send me a private message and correct it instead of a negative comment and judgment !!!

Comment: It wasn't a negative comment, I was merely stating a fact. I didn't want to edit the answer because I thought you might not know how to format it properly (since it was originally wrong), and by making you fix it you would learn how to format your answers. I'm sorry if you were offended. My only intention was to help you write a better answer.

Comment: Sorry but the tone of your response seemed very aggressive.
Anyway thanks for the help, I think I learned to write properly with this editor;
I rewrote a new answer with code comments.

Comment: It would have been better if you edited this answer, than to provide another answer with the same information.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code snippet that will help you with the toggle button animation if you would like to. You only need to add the functions that you want to execute when clicking of course, that's up to you.

```
'''
    import tkinter as tk

    # --- functions ---

    def move(steps=10, distance=0.1):
        if steps > 0:
            # get current position
            relx = float(frame.place_info()['relx'])

            # set new position
            frame.place_configure(relx=relx+distance)

            # repeate it after 10ms
            root.after(10, move, steps-1, distance)

    def toggle(event):
        if button["text"] == "Yes":
            move(25, 0.02)  # 50*0.02 = 1
            button["text"] = "No"
            print("Clicked on yes")
        elif button["text"] == "No":
            move(25, -0.02)
            button["text"] = "Yes"
            print("Clicked on no")


    # --- main --

    root = tk.Tk()

    frame = tk.Frame(root, background='red')
    frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=0.5, relheight=1)

    # to center label and button
    #frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    #frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    #frame.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)




    button = tk.Button(frame, text='Yes',width=5,height=1)
    button.place(relx=0.25,rely=0.5,relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.1)
    button.bind("<Button-1>",toggle)


    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Albe's answer is good but it has some bad coding practices.

Following the same steps:

```
Import Tkinter as tk 
top = tk.TK()
```

Define your function here and make it work for any button, not hard coded to the specific button you might use.

```
def toggle(button: tk.Button):
    if button.config('relief')[-1] == 'sunken':
        button.config(relief="raised")
    else:
        button.config(relief="sunken")
```

Then create and pack all the toggle buttons you want.

```
toggleButton = tk.Button(text="Toggle", width=12, relief="sunken",
command =lambda:toggle(toggleButton))
toggleButton.pack(pady=5)
top.mainloop()
```

This is better for two reasons. Creating the button object twice is redundant and will lead to buggy code. Hard coding the button to a specific toggle function is unscalable. This solution makes the code reusable and simple to add to. For example, replace that last block with:

```
for _ in range(4):
    b = tk.Button(text="Toggle", width=12, relief="sunken")
    b['command']= lambda a=b:toggle(a)
    b.pack(pady=5)
```

And now you get 4 toggling buttons without any additional functions or copy/paste