# How to make tkinter toggle button class by deriving from tkinter.Button?

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter

I am trying to make a **toggle** button class by deriving from the `tkinter.Button` object. To that end, I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23152307/how-to-create-a-tkinter-toggle-button) StackOverflow answer and [these](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/429838/simple-tkinter-toggle-button) code examples.

**The problem** is that I get my desired toggle behavior from the button **only after I click it twice**; the first two clicks, it does not enact the `self.config(relief="sunken")`. I tried using the `command` keyword argument sample from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27107533/10755836) answer and that works from the start.

```
import tkinter as tk

class ToggleButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, toggle_text="Toggled", toggle_bg_color="green", **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)

        self.toggled = False

        self.default_bg_color = self['bg']
        self.default_text = self["text"]

        self.toggle_bg_color = toggle_bg_color
        self.toggle_text = toggle_text

        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.toggle, add="+")

    def toggle(self, *args):
        if self["relief"] == "sunken":
            self["bg"] = self.default_bg_color
            self["text"] = self.default_text
            self.config(relief="raised")
            # self["relief"] = "raised"
            self.toggled = False
        else:
            self["bg"] = self.toggle_bg_color
            self["text"] = self.toggle_text
            # self["relief"] = "sunken"
            self.config(relief="sunken")
            self.toggled = True

def button_placeholder():
    print("TO BE IMPLEMENTED")


root = tk.Tk()

button = ToggleButton(parent=root,
                toggle_text="ON", toggle_bg_color="green",
                text="OFF", command=button_placeholder)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Here are screenshots of the behavior of the buttons after numerous clicks
[image: Screenshots of a button with clicks]

After the first two clicks on the button, the expected behavior occurs. However, if the user focuses on another window (for instance by minimizing the tkinter window) and then back, again the first two clicks do not cause the desired behavior.

Can some explain this? If not, can someone provide a solution where I can have consistent behavior on toggling my button?

Information about my system

- Windows 10; 64 bit
- Python 3.7.3 (64 bit)
- Tkinter 8.6

Comment: Add `return 'break'` at the end of `toggle()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you seem to have is that the `bg` parameter is not defined when you first create the button; it only gets a value assigned upon the first button press.

Then, the logic to toggle is hard to follow: you have a `self.toggled` boolean, yet you are testing if the button is `sunken` or not to differentiate between states...

I reorganized the logic to make it easier to follow; after all, toggle is a binary change from one state to another. I therefore placed the definition of the `ON` and `OFF` states in the body of the class (into two class dictionaries), and the code swaps the two configs upon toggling.

## On Windows:

```
import tkinter as tk


class ToggleButton(tk.Button):

    ON_config = {'bg': 'green',
                 'text': 'button is ON',
                 'relief': 'sunken',
                 }
    OFF_config =  {'bg': 'white',
                 'text': 'button is OFF',
                 'relief': 'raised',
                 }

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.toggled = False
        self.config = self.OFF_config
        self.config_button()

        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.toggle)

    def toggle(self, *args):
        if self.toggled:   # True = ON --> toggle to OFF
            self.config = self.OFF_config
        else:
            self.config = self.ON_config
        self.toggled = not self.toggled
        return self.config_button()

    def config_button(self):
        self['bg'] = self.config['bg']
        self['text'] = self.config['text']
        self['relief'] = self.config['relief']
        return "break"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self['text']}, {self['bg']}, {self['relief']}"


def button_placeholder():
    print('toggling now!')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()

    button = ToggleButton(root)
    button.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

## On OSX:

Where the buttons aspect is fixed, using a `tk.Label` can mimic the desired behavior:

```
import tkinter as tk


class ToggleButtonLBL(tk.Label):

    ON_config = {'bg': 'green',
                 'text': 'button is ON',
                 'relief': 'sunken',
                 }
    OFF_config =  {'bg': 'white',
                 'text': 'button is OFF',
                 'relief': 'raised',
                 }

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, command=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.toggled = False
        self.config = self.OFF_config
        self.config_button()

        self.bind("<Button-1>", self._toggle_helper)
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self._toggle)
        self.command = command

    def _toggle_helper(self, *args):
        return 'break'

    def _toggle(self, dummy_event):
        self.toggle()
        self.cmd()

    def toggle(self, *args):
        if self.toggled:   # True = ON --> toggle to OFF
            self.config = self.OFF_config
        else:
            self.config = self.ON_config
        self.toggled = not self.toggled
        self.config_button()
        return 'break'

    def config_button(self):
        self['bg'] = self.config['bg']
        self['text'] = self.config['text']
        self['relief'] = self.config['relief']
        return "break"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self['text']}, {self['bg']}, {self['relief']}"

    def cmd(self):
        self.command()


def button_placeholder():
    print('toggling now!')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()

    button = ToggleButtonLBL(root, command=button_placeholder)
    button.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried out your code and I still have the button raised for the first two clicks. And the toggle logic there was a test, I forgot to revert it back to using `self.toggle` when making this post.

Comment: I tried this (and I also tried this before while I was tinkering with this myself), it doesnt work. Makes me think that it could be something system specific. are you also on windows and python 3?

Comment: okay, one last try: inheriting from `tk.Label` instead of `tk.Button`, assigning a custom `command` handling, responding to `Button-1` and `<ButtonRelease>`, in order to mimic the functioning of a proper `tk.Button` - let me know how that worked this time.

Comment: ok. now it works as expected. I wonder what was going wrong. It seems that adding the `return "break"` at the end of the `toggle` method is sufficient as suggested by @acw1668

Comment: think you should change your answer and **just** put the `return "break"` and remove the other additions as they clutter the cause of the problem.

Comment: In win10 it does not require binding `<ButtonRelease-1>` nor the `_toggle_helper` method.