# Toggle tkinter window visibility

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to toggle tkinter window visibility when I click `p`.

```
toggle = True

if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
    toggle = not toggle

if toggle:
    app.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0)
else:
    app.wm_attributes("-alpha", 1)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23152307/how-to-create-a-tkinter-toggle-button https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/191477/binding-a-keyboard-key-to-a-tkinter-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what `keyboard` is though I am using it is the `keyboard` library. Anyway you can use `tkinter` itself for this. Here is an example to set you up:

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
toggle = True # Initially true

def check(e):
    global toggle 
    if toggle: # If true
        app.attributes('-alpha',0) # Then hide
        toggle = False # Set it to False
    else: # If not true
        toggle = True 
        app.attributes('-alpha',1) # Bring it back

app.bind('<p>',check) # Bind to the 'p' key.

app.mainloop()
```

Also keep a note that `wm_attributes()` and `attributes()` are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I have a problem. The window disappears when I click p, but when I click it again it does not appear.

Comment: @Pera16 I am terribly sorry, I made a mistake while copy pasting, try again now.